# How to prove these two boolean expressions are the same using boolean theorem?

Tags: boolean-algebra

**Expression 1**: $Y = B'C' + B'A' + A'C$.

**Expression 2**: $Y = B'C' + A'C$.

Both of the expressions generate the same truth table which implies they are the same.

However, how do you demonstrate they are the same using just boolean theorem?

If both expressions are the same, then it implies that $B'A' = 0$ and how do you get this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't imply $B'A'=0$.  It implies $B'A' \Rightarrow B'C'+A'C$.

If $B'$ and $A'$ are both true, then either $C$ is true, in which case $A'C$ is true, or $C'$ is true, in which case $B'C'$ is true.  Thus, $B'A' \Rightarrow B'C'+A'C$.

Answer (score 0):

This statement: "... it implies that $B′A′=0$ .." is not correct. It rather means that in case $B′A′$ is $1$ then will at least one of $B′C′$ and $A′C$ also be $1$. Consequently, $B′A′$ won't have any impact on the final result.

It can be proven like this.

Use that ($X'$ + $X$) is always $1$ and that multiplying a term by $1$ doesn't change the result.

Therefor you can rewrite **Expression 1** like:

$Y = B'C' + B'A' + A'C$

$Y = (A' + A)B'C' + (C' + C)B'A' + (B' + B)A'C$

$Y = A'B'C' + AB'C' + C'B'A' + CB'A' + B'A'C + BA'C$

Write all terms to be A folowed by B followed by C:

$Y = A'B'C' + AB'C' + A'B'C' + A'B'C + A'B'C + A'BC$

Remove the terms that appear twice:

$Y = A'B'C' + AB'C' + A'B'C + A'BC$

$Y = (A' + A)B'C' + (B' + B)A'C$

$Y = B'C' + A'C$

which is **Expression 2**.

Another way to look at it is:

**Case 1:** $B'A'$ is $0$

This is trivial as **Expression 1** becomes identical to **Expression 2** when $B'A'$ is $0$

**Case 2:** $B'A'$ is $1$

In this case **Expression 1** will give the result $1$

It is also known that $A'$ is $1$ and $B'$ is $1$. This can be inserted into **Expression 2** like:

$Y = B′C′ + A′C = 1C' + 1C = C' + C = 1$

So **Expression 2** will also give the result $1$

Consequently, **Expression 1** and **Expression2** will give the same result in all cases.